# Getting image attachments in FlexSlider for Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying create a function that will load image attachments of a post into a list for FlexSlider to use. To specify, I want an image slider that is specific to a certain post. There may be many sliders on one page depending on the post type (in this case, the image slider type) I want.

I've run into an issue, however. This is in my functions.php file, a variation of Marty Spellerberg's jQuery Slideshow article (I would post a link but I can't post more than 2 links with less than 10 rep):

```
function flexslider($post_id) {
global $post;

$images = get_children(array('post_parent' => $post_id,
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order ID'
));

if ($images) :

    foreach ($images as $attachment_id => $image) :

        $img_title = $image->post_title;

        $img_alt = get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
        if ($img_alt == '') : $img_alt = $img_title; endif;

        $big_array = image_downsize( $image->ID, 'large' );
        $img_url = $big_array[0];

        ?>
        <li><img src="<?php echo $img_url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $img_alt; ?>" title="<?php echo $img_title; ?>" /></li>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif;

}
```

And this is what's calling the function in index.php:

```
<div class="flexslider">
   <ul class="slides">
      <?php flexslider('large','$post->ID'); ?>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is, it's only showing up on the permalink page. I want it to show up wherever the post is shown.

An example can be seen here: [permalink](http://appearlythemes.com/themes/arctic/wordpress/) and [homepage](http://appearlythemes.com/themes/arctic/wordpress/).

Edit: Updated double quotes to singular quotations as per suggestion from comment.

Comment: *sidenote:* no need to surround variables with double quotes.

Comment: I will keep that in mind and make an appropriate change. Thank you, @ShivanRaptor!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. I basically did something a bit similar, but compressed it into one function. [You can find more details on my blog](http://www.premiumdw.com/tutorials/create-a-flexslider-gallery-using-attachment-images-in-wordpress/).

```
<?php

function add_flexslider() { // display attachment images as a flexslider gallery

    $attachments = get_children(array('post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order',  'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image','caption' => $attachment->post_excerpt, ));

    if ($attachments) { // see if there are images attached to posting ?>

    <!-- Begin Slider -->
    <div  class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">

    <?php // create the list items for images with captions

    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {

    echo '<li>';
    echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'large');
    echo '<p>';
    echo get_post_field('post_excerpt', $attachment->ID);
    echo '</p>';
    echo '</li>';

    } ?>

    </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- End Slider -->

    <?php } // end see if images

} // end add flexslider

?>
```